# Unable to delete record in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**home.php**
This is my controller, I am getting right URL through Id but unable to delete record.

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller
{       
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('select');
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    }

  public function index(){  
     //load the database  
     //$this->load->database();  
     //load the model  
     $this->load->model('select');  
     //load the method of model  
     $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
     //return the data in view  
     $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);  
  }   

  function records(){
      $ytl['dta']=$this->users->datas();
       //$this->load->view('info',$ytl);
       //echo "<pre>controller";print_r($ytl);
  }

  function primezone(){ 
       $ytl['dta']=$this->users->datas();
    echo "<pre>controller";print_r($ytl);
  }

  function form($id=null){
    //die($id);
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        //echo"<pre>";print_r( $this->input->post());die;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required|callback_check_picture[lname]');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile Number','required|callback_valid_phone_number[mobile]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h1 class="error">', '</h1>'); 
        if($this->form_validation->run()==True)
        {
            $data=[
            'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
            'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'mobile'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
            'message'=>$this->input->post('message'),
            ];
            if(empty($id))
            {
              $ytl=$this->select->insertdata($data);

            } else {
                $ytl=$this->select->updatedata($data,$id);
            }
          if($ytl){
              $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added.');
          redirect('home');
          }
        } else {
                //$this->load->view('form');
        }
    }
    $ytl['dta']=$this->select->getDataById($id);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($ytl);die;
    $this->load->view('form',$ytl); 
  }

  public function check_picture($a){
    if(!is_numeric($a))
    {
       return true;
    }else{
       $this->form_validation->set_message('check_picture', 'Please enter only char value');
       return False;
    }
  }

  function valid_phone_number($value){
  $value = strlen($value);
   //echo $value;die;
    if ($value == 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_phone_number', 'Mobile number not in range'); //{10} 
        return false;
    }
  }

  public function delete(){
    $this->load->model('select');
    $id=$this->input->get('id');
       //echo $id; 
     if($this->select->deleteuser($id))
     {
         $data['h']=$this->select->select();
         $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);
     } 
  }
}
?>
```

**fetch_view.php**
This is my view, I am getting right URL through Id but unable to delete record.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
     .error{color:red}
   </style>
</head>    
    <body>
      <h1>User List</h1>
      <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')){?>
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> <?= $this->session->flashdata('message') ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>

    <table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </tbody>
      <?php
          foreach ($h->result() as $row)
        { ?>
        <tr>  
          <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->mobile; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->message; ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?= site_url('home/form').'/'.$row->id ?>">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/delete').'/'.$row->id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
  </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**select.php**
This is my Model, I am getting right URL through Id but unable to delete record.

```
<?php   
class select extends CI_model
{
    function __construct(){  
      // Call the Model constructor  
      parent::__construct(); 
      $this->load->database();    
    }

    function insertdata($data){
      if(!empty($data['id'])){      
          $this->db->where('id', $data['id'])->update('student', $data);
          return $data['id'];
      } else {
          unset($data['id']);
          $this->db->insert('student',  $data);
          return $this->db->insert_id();
      }
    }


    public function select(){  
       //data is retrive from this query    
        $query = $this->db->get('student');  
        return $query;  
        //return $query->row();
    } 

    function getDataById($id)
    {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->where('id',$id);
      $this->db->from('student');
      $query = $this->db->get()->row_array();  
           return $query; 
    }

    function updatedata($data, $id)
    {
      //print_r($data);die;
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      return $this->db->update('student' ,$data);
    }


    public function deleteuser($id)     
    {  
      //echo $id;
      //die;
      // $this->load->database();
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->delete('student');
      return true;
    }

}    
?>
```

[image]

---

I know that I have to paste only specific code but I am pasting full code.

Comment: did you get the id when echoed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to help you

```
<body>
 echo $msg;
.....your code....
  <a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/home/delete/" . $row->id; ?>">Delete</a>
```

home.php

```
  public function index($msg = NULL){  
     $this->load->model('select');   
         $data = array(
         'h' => $this->select->select(),
         'msg' => $msg
          );
     $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);  
  } 
         public function delete()  

          {
         $this->load->model('select');
         $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
         //echo $id;
         $result=  $this->select->deleteuser($id);
         if($result==TRUE)
         {
         $msg = '<script>alert("delete successful!!! ")</script>';
           $this->index($msg);
         } 
    }
```

select.php

```
 public function select(){  
   //data is retrive from this query  
    $this->db->select('*');  
    $query = $this->db->get('student');  
    return $query;  
    //return $query->row();
} 

 public function deleteuser($id=NULL)     
    {  

     $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $result= $this->db->delete('student');
     return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Sir Its working but after delete record its show me double entry of User List (fetch_view) .

Comment: I updated my answer. in the screenshot there are no error only 2 records show.That's you mean .You have data more than it in the databases

Comment: Sir Its working but after delete record its show me double entry of User List (fetch_view), I have attached screenshot

Comment: peer reviewed. pending

Comment: After delete record I have seen double User List, On this URL you can understand double entry I have created.

http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/home/delete/9

User List
First Name Last Name Email Mobile Number Message Update Delete  (next line) 

User List
First Name Last Name Email Mobile Number Message Update Delete

Comment: I simulated your code in localhost.now work fine.without any problem

Answer (score 3):

You called in the url delete($id) function but not pass the id in the controller .Change your delete function.

```
public function delete($id='')  
{
     $this->load->model('select');
     if(!empty($id))
     {
        $data['deldata']=$this->select->deleteuser($id);
        $data['h']=$this->select->select();               
        $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);
     } 
}
```

Comment: In your model It would be good practice to check for $id being an integer.

`if (!is_int($id)) { 
    throw new \Exception('$id must be an integer when trying to delete something');
}`

Comment: Sir Its working but after delete my record its giving me error, the screenshot I have attached.

Comment: Ok so what does var_dump($data['h']) ( after your select call) show you?

Comment: @kumar what is the error ? in the screenshot there are no error only 2 records show.

Comment: I have edit your question so i cant find your screenshot can you plz upload again?

Comment: Hi @Kumar: please check again my answer. The error will be solved ;)